# Multiple CheckBox Selection Result using Linq without hardcoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

Illustration of database (actual column and table name is different)

```
EmployeeeID      IsSicked   IsRetired    IsHoliday  
1                false      false        true
2                true       false        true
3                true       true         true
4                false      false        false
```

**What problem am I having?** 
I have a checkbox for IsSicked, IsRetired and IsHoliday in my application, which allow user to check multiple selection and submit. 
The system will return list of employee from database based on the selection of user. For example, when user tick IsSicked and IsRetired, system will return list of user who is sicked and is retired from database.

Based on below code, I need to write 2^3 = 8 possibilities to get the result.
As the column expand to n columns(exluding employeeID column), I will need to write 2^n if else statement to get the query.
If there are 10 column (10 checkboxes selection), then i need to write 2^10 = 1024 if else statement

It seems to me that this supposed to be quite a common problem faced by developers, unfortunately i can't find a good solution to this online

**Expectation of solution** 
Generic combination of C# code and/or LINQ query that no need hard code the logic as below if(...) else if (...)

```
var employee = db.Employee.AsQueryable():
if(model.IsSicked == true)
{
    employee.Where(z => z.IsSicked == true)
}
else if(model.IsRetired == true)
{
    employee.Where(z => z.IsRetired == true)
}
...
...

else if(model.IsSicked == true && model.IsRetired == true)
{
    employee.Where(z => z.IsSick == true || z.IsRetired == true)
}
else if (model.IsSicked == true && model.IsRetired == true && model.IsHoliday == true)
{
    employee.Where(z => z.IsSick == true || z.IsRetired == true || z.IsHoliday == true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use library called LINQKit and use its [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to create predicate with dynamic ORs.

```
var employee = db.Employee.AsQueryable():
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Employee>();
if (model.IsSicked == true)
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.IsSick == model.IsSick);
if (model.IsRetired == true)
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.IsRetired == model.IsRetired);
if (model.IsHoliday == true)
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.IsHoliday == model.IsHoliday);
var result = employee.AsExpandable().Where(c => predicate.Invoke(c)).ToList()
```

Comment: @Estagra I have added an example

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a `enum` with `[Flags]`:

```
[Flags]
public enum EmployeeStatus
{
    None = 0,
    Sick = 1,
    Retired = 2,
    Holiday = 4
}
```

In your database you can store this as an integer.

Your model becomes similar to

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public EmployeeStatus Status { get; set }
}
```

then LINQ queries become similar to:

```
employee.Where(z => z.Status == EmployeeStatus.Sick)
```

Because of using `[Flags]` you can do the following for multiple states, e.g. sick and retired:

```
employee.Where(z => z.Status == (EmpoyeeStatus.Sick | EmployeeStatus.Retired))
```

Please note that `|` is the boolean OR which translates in the following:

```
  EmpoyeeStatus.Sick | EmployeeStatus.Retired
= 1 | 2
= b01 | b10
= b11
= 3
```

so effectively works as "and" in our logic.

Comment: As I have mentioned earlier in the post, the table name and column above is illustration and does not represent the real table i am working on. Indeed, the solution you provide is good where the assumption made is the employee can be only exactly one of the status that you mentioned above. What am i working here is a solution where an employee could be sick and retired at the same time, or sick, retired or holiday at a same time (which might not seems logical in this case)

Comment: @Estagra I've updated the answer to show that you can do this with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can build up your Where predicate like this:

```
var employee = db.Employee.AsQueryable():

if(model.IsSicked == true)
    employee = employee.Where(z => z.IsSicked == true)

if(model.IsRetired == true)
    employee = employee.Where(z => z.IsRetired == true)

if (model.IsHoliday == true)
    employee = employee.Where(z => z.IsHoliday == true)
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
employee.Where(z => (z.IsSicked || !model.IsSicked) &&
                    (z.IsRetired || !model.IsRetired) &&
                    (z.IsHoliday || !model.IsHoliday))
```

Comment: wasn't the first answer you provide filter isSicked == true first, then only filter IsRetired == true which results in lesser outcome if there are multiple true, it should be more or equal outcome if there are multiple true since it is or